# Algorithm to find specific set of integers within sorted set

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I need an effective algorithm to find a subset of integers within a set that meet the conditions:

- The sum of sub-set items <= the "limit"
- prefer to pick the subset with maximum values that fit the limit as close as possible.

Examples:
if the set after sort is {3,2,2} and "limit" is {4}, the subset would be {2,2}

if the set after sort is {3,2,2,1,1} and "limit" is {4}, the subset would be {3,1}

if the set after sort is {3,3,1} and "limit" is {5}, the subset would be {3,1}

Comment: This seems to be a simple form of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). As you can see at the link, there are fairly good approximative solutions, but an exact solution will not be efficient (as it is NP-hard).

Comment: Check out Wikipedia article on [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and the book *Approximation Algorithms* by Vijay V. Vazirani.

Comment: Please anwer your own question, and accept it to close the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Moving comments into the answer box, which the OP never did:

> This seems to be a simple form of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). As you can see at the link, there are fairly good approximative solutions, but an exact solution will not be efficient (as it is NP-hard). *– Marc van Leeuwen*
>
> Check out Wikipedia article on [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and the book [Approximation Algorithms](http://books.google.com/books/about/Approximation_Algorithms.html?id=EILqAmzKgYIC&redir_esc=y) by Vijay V. Vazirani. *– user2468*